# Akka.net and angular

Tags: angular, typescript, akka.net

I am new to akka.net.Can anyone please provide few examples on publishing the message to angular page? also, suggest any good examples I could refer to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Angular as a client application can communicate with your server either via HTTP request/response or by using web sockets. At the moment Akka.NET didn't port HTTP module for handling any of those directly.

However, what you can do, is to nest Akka `ActorSystem` inside your web server (it can be a static resource or a singleton dependency if you're using containers for Dependency Injection) and expose it from there using a framework of your choice i.e. by communicating with it using ASP.NET controllers or SignalR hubs.